# How to write the name of a foreign Master's degree from a non-English speaking country on a resume?

Tags: formal-language

What is the formal way of writing the name of a Master's degree from a different country on a resume? I am confused about the following options:

1. Master’s in Exploration Informatique des Données et Décisionnel
2. Master’s in 'Exploration Informatique des Données et Décisionnel'
3. Master of Exploration Informatique des Données et Décisionnel

Comment: I would probably translate it. One could run into difficulties because international systems of higher education sometimes arrange their degrees differently. If a degree didn't correlate directly to "master's," I might use the original term.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for our sister site, [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [This wiki page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatique_d%C3%A9cisionnelle) suggests some English equivalents

Comment: @AndyBonner the translation is bit wired and not accurate 'Computer Data Exploration and Decision Making'

Comment: Yes, that's what Google Translate gave me, but the wiki page on _informatique décisionnelle_ suggests that it's a bad translation. It looks to me like this is not about computer data but about business strategy?

Comment: I would simply find an English-speaking colleague (or a French-speaking one who's faced this challenge before) and see what's preferred for this field.

Comment: For the *name of the degree* (eg MA or BSc) I'd just use whatever in printed on the certificate.  For the description of of the course content, I'd translate (but I wouldn't use google translate)

Comment: @AndyBonner, the master is about data science even though the name is strange.